# Ember.js component actions not fired

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to make a reusable ember component. I want to add an action to this component, so when the user clicks a button somethings happen. The problem is, that this action is not been called. I am doing it this way:

**DummyComponent.js**

```
App.DummyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    dummy_action: function() {
      console.log('dummy_action fired!');
    } 
  } 
});
```

**dummy-component.hbs**

```
<p>dummy component</p>
<button {{action "dummy_action"}}>Dummy action</button>
```

The component is rendering correctly when I include in my *application.hbs*:

```
{{ dummy-component }}
```

But as I said, the action is not beeing fired.

If I create an action in my controller using the same approach, the action is called correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Thans!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [component guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/defining-a-component/):

> Note: Components must have a dash in their name. So blog-post is an
>   acceptable name, but post is not. This prevents clashes with current
>   or future HTML element names, and ensures Ember picks up the
>   components automatically.

An example is available [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/folog/1/edit).

Whenever ember find an unknown helper name, it tries to resolve it with [ComponentLookup](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages_es6/ember-handlebars/lib/component_lookup.js). In your case, the component template is successfully resolved but it cannot find your component in the container and register/assign a default Ember.Component which does not implement your action handler.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

create a view:

```
MainAppView = Ember.View.extend({
   actions: {
       dummy_action: function() {
          console.log('dummy_action fired!');
      } 
    } 
});
```

then in your template:

```
{{#view MainAppView}}
   <p>dummy component</p>
   <button {{action dummy_action target="view"}}>Dummy action</button>

{{/view}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @juan-jardim.Yes that works, but I am trying to make a reusable component, and i'm wondering why the actions do not work in components. As far as I know, the documentation is pretty clear about this: http://emberjs.com/guides/components/handling-user-interaction-with-actions/

Comment: Maybe you have to define the target of your action

Comment: I am not sure about that... the documentation says this: "By default, the {{action}} helper will send the action to the view's target, which is generally the view's controller. (Note: in the case of an Ember.Component, the default target is the component itself.)" http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_specifying-a-target